# Can I force Windows 11 not to have a separate taskbar icon for an opened Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, taskbar

This might seem the very definition of a 1st World Problem but it's driving me nuts!
[image]

So the right-hand icon is my opened Visual Studio project, and to its left is the icon for Visual Studio 2022.  In previous versions of Windows (10) and VS (2019) there was a single Visual Studio icon, which was either plain (no open VS projects) or decorated with a mark at the bottom to show that there was an open project.  I'd like to return to that happy place but I can't figure out how.  There is no property that I can find on the Taskbar nor in VS itself.

Comment: I would be tempted to unpin the VS 2022 icon and repin it from the opened project. I've come across this before with other apps after updating them.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this seems to be a Windows 11 bug. I have the same problem for another program than VS. After unpinning the old icon and pinning the new, the problem is solved for a few days until it occures again. Hope it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

The answer (so far) seems to be, as @phuzi said, to unpin VS2022.  I then closed the project and repinned VS 2022.  There is now only one icon - result.